# Why telegram bot don't work if participants left group or new one add to group?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

When I run my app and someone in group left or new participant add to group, my bot stop working.

Below you can see code of my app:

```js
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

const token = '1928095766:AAGf5aU7E1_FAM_fWzQs3SSGy-1AJS0DjcY';

const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });


bot.on('message', async msg => {
                const reg = /\d\d\-\d\d$/;
                if (msg.text.match(reg)) {
                    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Gh')
                }
            
})
```

And what I received in terminal if someone left group or new one add into, when my app is running:

```js
(node:21155) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at TelegramBot.<anonymous> (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/reminder.js:11:30)
    at TelegramBot.emit (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/eventemitter3/index.js:182:35)
    at TelegramBot.processUpdate (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js:634:12)
    at /Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegramPolling.js:110:22
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegramPolling.js:106:17
    at tryCatcher (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/romansavka/Telegram-Bot-Node/telegram-bot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:462:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:21155) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21155) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the message received has no attribute text, so the error raised `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

Comment: How can I avoid this TypeError?